# Photos messed up after copying from a usb drive

Tags: data-corruption, file-transfer

It looks all messed up. I can see the preview of the photo but when I open it, it is just bars of colors. When I tried to upload it here to show you guys, it said framing is not allowed and wouldn't let me upload it. Anyone how to fix it? I will appreciate it very much as they are all wedding photos.

Well, the duplicate question does not answer my question nor does it give me a solution. If you open your eyes and look, the images are totally different. Mine is completely messed up and that other photo isn't that bad. So, if you want to mark it as duplicate, at least make it so the other question has a SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM.

On another note, I am able to preview the images fine with a medium thumbnail setting. When I change it to large, I see the messed up image. By preview, I mean see the thumbnails in the folder.

[image: as you can see it is all messed up]

Comment: Take a screenshot of the photo on your screen, and upload the screenshot. It's likely this question is a duplicate, but having an example of what your seeing will help us make that determination, and decide which existing question will answer yours.

Comment: And as for solving your problem: as the other answer suggests, first try transferring onto another computer to see if the problem is on your computer or on the USB drive. If it's on the computer, problem solved. If it's on the drave, **there is no magic solution because the images are gone**.

Comment: I agree with Matt and I would suggest that you might want to read the [relevant portion](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) of our Help for some additional consideration.

Comment: Note also, too that the reason that the thumbnails appear to not be corrupted at small sizes is there are likely thumbnails in the metadata. So, theorically you could "recover" your images by extracting the thumbnails. Note, however, that the thumbnails are likely to be such a low resolution that they won't be of much use. -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349622/extract-thumbnail-from-jpeg-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a corrupt JPEG file.

Do you still have access to the original source of the images (ideally the camera's storage card)? If so, check whether the images are OK in there and copy them again; that would be the method most likely to lead to success.

If you cannot do that (or find that the images are already corrupt on the card), there are tools that claim to be able to fix such files:

- http://www.stellarinfo.com/jpeg-repair.php
- http://file-repair.en.softonic.com/
- http://vg-jpeg-repair.software.informer.com/

However, there can be no guarantee of success. It depends most of all on how much the files are damaged. If there was only a single bit flipped, then it could be possible to find and correct it by analzing the image, but if the damage is larger then nothing can be done.

And the fact that *all* pictures were damaged does not bode well in that regard.

Comment: Tried the first 2 and they were completely useless. The last one wanted me to pay before I can try it out which sounds like a scam.

Comment: @khuderm: as I wrote: a systematic error is likely large and therefore not fixable at all. That's the disadvantage of compression.